# Getting NULL from this SELECT CASE STATEMENT

Tags: postgresql, case

So I have this code below, where its supposed to return true or false depending on the current day, the problem is that I'm getting a `null`.
Apparently when I tried putting a date like `11-08-2017` (Wednesday), I'm able to get a `false` as expected. However it doesn't work on other days.
Anyone knows why I'm getting this null return?

```
select (CASE upper(to_char(now()::timestamp without time zone,'Day')) 
 WHEN 'SUNDAY'
  THEN ('false'::boolean)
 WHEN 'MONDAY'
  THEN ('false'::boolean)
 WHEN 'TUESDAY'
  THEN ('false'::boolean)
 WHEN 'WEDNESDAY' -- works
  THEN ('false'::boolean)
 WHEN 'THURSDAY'
  THEN ('false'::boolean)
 WHEN 'FRIDAY'
  THEN ('true'::boolean)
 WHEN 'SATURDAY'
  THEN ('false'::boolean)
END) as res;
```

Output:

`res
(null)`

PS:

This code: `select upper(to_char(now()::timestamp without time zone,'Day'))` works and always has output. Just that when I add a CASE within it, it returns a `null`.

Comment: `'false'::boolean` can be simplified to `false`

Comment: Why not simply `select extract(isodow from current_date) = 5` if you want to test if today is friday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the immediate cause of your problem is that there is trailing *whitespace* after the day names.  Wrapping your expression for the day of the week with `trim` seems to fix the problem:

```
select
    case trim(upper(to_char(now()::timestamp without time zone,'Day'))) 
    when 'SUNDAY'
    then ('false'::boolean)
    when 'MONDAY'
    then ('false'::boolean)
    when 'TUESDAY'
    then ('false'::boolean)
    when 'WEDNESDAY' -- works
    then ('false'::boolean)
    when 'THURSDAY'
    then ('false'::boolean)
    when 'FRIDAY'
    then ('true'::boolean)
    when 'SATURDAY'
    then ('false'::boolean)
    end as res;
```

As the answer given by @Used_By_Already mentioned, you might want to extract the numeric day of week from your date column instead of going this route.

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead

```
extract(dow from  current_timestamp)
- This returns 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday,...,6 for Saturday.
```

Don't rely on language strings, much better to use numbers.

for testing:

```
select
*
, case extract(dow from  dd)
    when 5 then 'true'::boolean else 'false'::boolean
  end
FROM generate_series
        ( '2017-11-01'::timestamp 
        , '2017-11-12'::timestamp
        , '1 day'::interval) dd
```

Comment: I need to know the day name, I have to check if a certain transaction can be made on certain days.

Comment: you need to know the dow that represents that dayname

Comment: Ok, it works now. Thanks! How come that language strings doesn't work well?

Comment: why run the risk of writing code that breaks by some setting? (maybe a french guy wants to run lang as french) the day of week numbers are universal, use the numbers.

Comment: No need for a `CASE`, you can simplify that to `extract(dow from dd) = 5`